# How to find out which columns make up the partitioning key of a partitioned table in Vertica

Tags: partitioning, vertica

I have a vertica table which is partitioned by one of its column 
I need to view which column the table is partitioned by, is there any system table which stores these information.

Answer (score 3):

you can use "tables" system table
for example:

```
dbadmin=> select partition_expression from tables where table_name ilike 'products';
           partition_expression
------------------------------------------
 date_trunc('month', PRODUCTS.CREATEDATE)
```

Comment: I needed column name (only CREATEDATE), how can i get that ?

Comment: In your case it always one column? coz in Vertica partition it's expression and can be combined from n columns and different functions. You can parse it with regexp functions